# Stop Timer from looping

Tags: javascript, html, timer

How can you stop a timer from looping here is an example of the code:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div><span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
      <button onclick="start5Timer()">start</button>
      <button onclick="resetTimer()">reset</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    let timerId;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    
     function resetTimer() {
          clearInterval(timerId);
          start5Timer();
        }

    function start5Timer() {
      var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
       startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    };

  </script>

</html>
```

Here is a link to the code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJQWAX7ZQK8B
it isnt a js fiddle its a W3 schools tryit editor

Comment: your tryit editor edition works fine.

Comment: maybe you can look this link to understand better [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), Basically, is using setInterval() to start and clearInterval() to stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

`start5Timer();` inside `resetTimer()` is restarting your timer.